# Reformulating latent dirichlet allocation

Tags: probability, latent-dirichlet-alloc, conditional

can you guys help me solve this equation and go from :

[image: p(w, z, θ, φ|α, β) = p(φ|β)p(θ|α)p(z|θ)p(w|phi_z )]

to this one : [image: p(θ, φ, z|w, α, β) = p(θ, φ, z, w|α, β)/p(w|α, β)]

I have tried something but my result gives me this : p(θ, φ, z| α, β) = p(θ, φ, z, w|α, β)/p(w|α, β)

the equations are taken from this paper : https://coli-saar.github.io/cl19/materials/darling-lda.pdf

Comment: Isn't this a standard definition of a conditional probability?  Feel free to ignore $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (they're merely along for the ride) and represent $(\theta,\phi,z)$ as a single (vector) variable -- say $\eta$ -- so that you are asking whether $p(\eta\mid w)=p(\eta,w)/p(w).$  What is there to show?

Comment: Thanks you so much !